# Использую FFMPEG в Node.js для Live Stream по UDP и есть проблемы с длительностью воспроизведения

Tags: c#, node.js, потоки-данных, udp, live

Реализовал поток аудио по UDP на сервер Node.js

Работает всё исправно и без задержек. Проблема в том, что спустя 4 минуты и 15-19 секунды, сервер перестаёт принимать буфер и воспроизведение прекращается, хотя по факту буфер поступает. Перезагружая сервер и запуская скрипт, они опять идут и звук воспроизводится, но до 4:15 - 4:19.

Вот мой код с Node.js:

```
var http = require("http");
var port = PORT;
var host = "IP";
var children = require("child_process");

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    //ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -i 'udp://IP:PORT' -b:a 128k -f webm -
    var ffm = children.spawn("ffmpeg", "-r 1 -f s16le -ar 8000 -ac 2 -i udp://IP:PORT-b:a 320k -f wav -".split(" "));
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "audio/wav; codecs=PCM", 'Cache-Control': 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'});
    ffm.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      res.write(data);

    });
}).listen(port, host);

console.log("Server running at http://" + host + ":" + port + "/");
```

Comment: пробовали поставить обработчик на stderr процесса? на событие error в res (может заодно и req)?

Comment: @nörbörnën, Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу это реализовать в коде, так как я  совсем новичок в Node.js

Comment: документация по spawn https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Comment: @nörbörnën, Супер, мне вроде бы как помогло то, что я добавил:
ffm.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });
    ffm.on("close", (code) => {
      console.log(`close: ${code}`);
    });

Возможно Вы мне подскажите как я могу сделать так, что когда подключается новый пользователь, он тоже мог слушать. Потому что сейчас можно слушать в одно соединение. Если открыть ссылку во втором окне, аудио не играет. После обновления страницы такая же ситуация.

Comment: скорее всего нужно написать так https://pastebin.com/dPCqk7SN, но я не проверял этот код

Comment: @nörbörnën, К сожалению проблема осталась. Я так понимаю из за того, что поток идёт на постоянной основе. Когда подключается новый пользователь идёт загрузка всех байтов, которые поступали. Загружается максимум 1мегабайт и на этом всё. Возможно Вы знаете как сделать так, что бы поток воспроизводился именно с того момента, когда подключается новый пользователь?